# Repeat two tasks every 0.1 ms and 0.3 ms (Systems.Timer.Timer not precise enough)

Tags: c#, .net, timer

1. Is there a way to execute a method in high resolution frequency in C#, e.g. every 100 microseconds?
2. What about two different methods at different frequencies, e.g. Method1 every 0.1 ms and Method2 0.3 ms?

MSDN has documentation on attaching an event handler to the `Systems.Timers.Timer` class like this:

```
public static void Main()
{

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Method);
    aTimer.Interval = 2000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
}
```

But `System.Timers.Timer` only has a 15~16 ms precision when I benchmarked it. My CPU's performance counter has 0.1 ms precision and below, but I cannot find a way to attach an event handler to the `Stopwatch` class.

Also, is there some threading issue that I need to be aware of when I am executing the two methods at different frequencies?

Thanks!

Comment: You should look at systems with realtime OSes if you need that sort of precision. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Comment: I agree with @tvanfosson, with time periods like this you are mrew likely to be impacted by stuff like multitasking

Comment: @tvanfosson: Thanks for the suggestion. For development time reasons, I have to work in .NET. I've read about RTOS'es but I am hoping there is a makeshift workaround in C#. The only part that I've found not within my control is that the GC freezes my application for <10 ms every few minutes, which is still bearable.

Comment: @AYK: I have a remotely-guided vehicle that is sending information to my workstation at several kHz, so processing time has to be comparable so it doesn't cause a bottleneck.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor Shouldn't it be possible to reduce these problems by giving the application its dedicated core(s)?

Comment: @ephedyn - have you thought about running your task slower and interpolating? is the vehicle moving quickly enough for the values to change significantly in 20+ ms?

Comment: You might be able to get the resolution you want using interop to the Win32 multimedia timers (if they haven't been added to the .NET framework yet). Here's an old article that outlines one possible solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework

Comment: @tvanfosson Yes. The vehicle acquires a few (likely) targets and needs to filter these images and my workstation has to predict then send commands for the vehicle to respond to their predicted movements. 20+ ms is not responsive enough unfortunately.

Comment: They have not been added, but that isa trivial excercse to add them via interop. Time for TimerQueues.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Just to double check, does timeBeginPeriod(1) instruct `System.Timers.Timer` to use the multimedia timer? I've used it successfully to increase the resolution of `DateTime` before, but haven't tried with `System.Timers.Timer`.

Comment: Timers is not a MultiMedia Timer. It is aregular thread Level timer object, so it is bound to the theread switching Resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ugly, but you may have some chance using the stopwatch ElapsedTicks.

```
Stopwatch w = new Stopwatch()
long nextTick = 0;
long ticksPerMicroSecond = 1000000L / Stopwatch.Frequency; // Number of ticks per microsec.
long periodInTicks = ticksPerMicroSecond / 100; // Ticks per 0.1ms

while(true)
{
  long currentTick = w.ElapsedTicks.
  if (currentTick  > nextTick)
  {
    nextTick = currentTick + periodInTicks;
    // Do something here.
  }
}
```

It is as ugly as it can get, and you get a while(true) loop, that will probably be using 100% cpu for free (better run this on a multi core, then).

You may want to benchmark the thing a bit (look at examples in Stopwatch.Frequency msdn doc), to see how precise your timer can be, and see the drift you get from being late with your inner function. You may also want to enable background gc to avoid GC blocking your thread. While this shows it is dable in code, I'm really not sure you can get your function run in less than 0.1ms.

Comment: +1. Seriously. This sucks but at the end if you need to go that low, then a spin - and that is waht you do here - is about all you can do.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. Windows is not a real time operating system.

Comment: -1. See, it is not possible because you wont find HARDWARE with this resolution and it is below what windows offers, but on moder nhardware winows IS able to offer a callback with 1 ms resolution given hardware provides it. TimerQueue has quite good guarantees. 0.1 and 0.3 is beyond what is considered reasonble, though - they had multimedia in mind, not something like... not sure what would ned 0.1ms.

Comment: @TomTom, consistent 0.1/0.3ms intervals are not possible because Windows have no guarantees about if thread will be scheduled for execution at any particular time. On top of that CLR have GC that may as well freeze all threads for undeterministic amopunt of time. So if one really need consistent intervals there is not much can be done in Windows.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually MS DOES have guarantees for high precision timer callbacks. The problem is that the API has a 1ms resolution. But you can get relible 1ms callbacks assuming the machine is not overloaded and your hardware has a 1ms HPET resolution. This is mostly used for audio / video playback, and a not too well known API. But again, it resolves at 1MS only. And CLR GC freezing your app TODAY is a beginner issue of a clueless person - someone who can not allow that just puts in the non-freezing gc, you know. Via configuration. Since .NET 4.5 that is actually not that hard.

Comment: @TomTom - I don't know exactly why you're downvoting me. You said in your own post that it's not possible. Also Windows isn't a real time operating system. Both of these statements are true so why the downvote?

Comment: After a long while hacking around scheduler, I agree that this is the most accurate answer, upvoted but I'll give Wam the chosen answer because it's the closest to implementation.

Answer (score -2):

Not possible. You are below what MS develoeprs considered reasonable.

The best yo ucan do- asssuming modern hardware - is TImerQueue, HPET. Can be disabled in bios, so tweaking there may be needed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686796(v=vs.85).aspx

No .NET API available, but this is trivial to map via Interop.

THAT SAID: the timing parameter there has a int period and is given  in millisecond, so we talk of a 1ms resolution only. And whether the hardware does that depends MOSTLY on age.

So, sorry, that is about the best you can get.